# android - bottom up animation in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-animation, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView and set the following animation for its subgroups:

```
  <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >

<translate
    android:duration="900"
    android:fromYDelta="500%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" >
</translate>

  </set>
```

So this is how it looks. Normal state:

[image]

When a group is expanded, the subgroups come from the bottom, overlaying the main groups for a moment:

[image]

What I need is that those subgroups do not overlay the main groups while the animation is in effect and slide up "from the background" of a main group like this:

[image]

Any ideas how to achieve that?